# How to compile xslt2-transformer.oxt LibreOffice extension

Tags: java, libreoffice

I am trying to compile the [xslt2-transformer](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/xslt2-transformer) extension, because I can’t find the LibreOffice extension `xslt2-transformer.oxt` on the web site (if anybody has it, he is welcome).

To build from source code, I proceeded like that:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/dtardon/xslt2-transformer.git
$ cd xslt2-transformer/
$ make
```

I am getting a lot of (similar) errors during build:

```
mkdir -p build/classes && \
    javac -d build/classes -source 1.5 -target 1.5 \
          -cp "external/saxon9.jar:" com/sun/star/comp/xsltfilter/Base64.java \
          com/sun/star/comp/xsltfilter/XSLTFilterOLEExtracter.java \
          com/sun/star/comp/xsltfilter/XSLTransformer.java && \
    touch build/javac.done
com/sun/star/comp/xsltfilter/XSLTFilterOLEExtracter.java:27: error: package com.sun.star.bridge does not exist
import com.sun.star.bridge.XBridgeFactory;
                          ^
com/sun/star/comp/xsltfilter/XSLTFilterOLEExtracter.java:28: error: package com.sun.star.bridge does not exist
import com.sun.star.bridge.XBridge;
                          ^
[...]
  symbol:   class XConnector
  location: class XSLTFilterOLEExtracter
com/sun/star/comp/xsltfilter/XSLTFilterOLEExtracter.java:321: error: cannot find symbol
        XConnector xConnector = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XConnector.class, x);
                                                          ^
  symbol:   class XConnector
  location: class XSLTFilterOLEExtracter
100 errors
1 warning
make: *** [build/javac.done] Error 1
```

I think my `CLASSPATH` is not up-to-date. I need to add the `com.sun.star` package and classes.

Since I am (currently) on OSX, my LibreOffice is installed on `/Applications/LibreOffice.app` and I found some classes in `./Contents/Resources/java`.

So I update the `CLASSPATH` that way:

```
export CLASSPATH=/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/Resources/java:$CLASSPATH
```

But, I have the same errors. How can I fix that?

**EDIT 1** put some jar in the `CLASSPATH`

I tried that:

```
$ export CLASSPATH=/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents//Resources/java/ridl.jar:.
```

I have less errors.

**EDIT 2** The build succeed!

I finally added the following jar files to the `CLASSPATH`:

```
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents//Resources/java/ridl.jar
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents//Resources/java/jurt.jar
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents//Resources/java/juh.jar
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents//Resources/java/unoil.jar
```

And I get the extension!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, to build from source code, I proceeded like that:

```
git clone https://github.com/dtardon/xslt2-transformer.git

cd xslt2-transformer/

export CLASSPATH=/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/Resources/java/ridl.jar:\
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/Resources/java/jurt.jar:\
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/Resources/java/juh.jar:\
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/Resources/java/unoil.jar

make
```

The result is `build/xslt2-transformer.oxt`.